# Replacement for Spark's CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark and am trying to optimize code written by another developer. The scenario is as follows:

1. There is a list of dictionaries with three key-value pairs. One is source:value, second is target:value and third is column:value.
2. CASE WHEN THEN statement is generated based on above three key-value pairs. For instance, the list of dictionaries is as follows:

```
values = [{'target': 'Unknown', 'source': '', 'column': 'gender'}, 
{'target': 'F', 'source': '0', 'column': 'gender'}, 
{'target': 'M', 'source': '1', 'column': 'gender'}, 
{'target': 'F', 'source': 'F', 'column': 'gender'}, 
{'target': 'F', 'source': 'Fe', 'column': 'gender'}]
```

3. The following code generates the CASE WHEN THEN statement that follows.

```
for value in values:
    source_value = value.get("source")
    op = op.when(df[column] == source, value.get("target"))
```

```
Column<'CASE WHEN (gender = ) THEN Unknown 
WHEN (gender = 0) THEN F 
WHEN (gender = 1) THEN M 
WHEN (gender = F) THEN F 
WHEN (gender = Fe) THEN F END'>
```

4. This CASE WHEN THEN is then used to select data from a dataframe.

Question: Is the usage of CASE WHEN THEN valid here (is it optimized)? Some of the CASE WHEN statements are very very lengthy (around 1000+). Is there a better way to redo the code (regex perhaps)?

I looked at the below questions, but were not relevant for my case.
[CASE WHEN ... THEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451287/case-when-then)
[SPARK SQL - case when then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157451/spark-sql-case-when-then)

Thanks.

Comment: I feel like this is better as a UDF with basic if-elif statements

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks. Is there a way to compare dictionaries instead of using CASE WHEN? Like, use 2 dictionaries, one with source and other with target and get a third one with the replaced values?

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives:

- Use [UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html), in which you can access a dictionary of values
- Build a table, and perform [broadcast join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435263/dataframe-join-optimization-broadcast-hash-join)

The way to know which is better is by examining the execution plan, job duration and total shuffle.